# What are the initial conditions for this coupled advection/transport system?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, initial-value-problems, hyperbolic-equations, transport-equation

Consider the coupled transport (i.e. advection) system

$$
\begin{align}
\partial_t u + b\partial_x \phi &= 0,\\
\partial_t \phi + b\partial_x u &= 0,
\end{align}
$$

where $u(x,t),\phi(x,t) \in C^2\left([0,1]\times \mathbb{R}^+\right)$ are unknown, and $b\in \mathbb{R}$ is given and constant.

By combining the equations, one can recover two classical, decoupled, wave equations:

$$\partial_{tt} u - b^2 \partial_{xx} u = 0$$

and similar for $\phi$. The latter accepts one initial condition for the unknown $u/\phi$, and another one for its time derivative $\partial_t u / \partial_t \phi$. The reason for this property - to my understanding - is the structure of d'Alembert's solution, see e.g. https://mathworld.wolfram.com/dAlembertsSolution.html for a derivation.

How can I use this knowledge to find the "correct" initial conditions for the coupled transport system? How many conditions are required and which?

---

Intuitively, I would think that I need one initial condition for $u$ and one for $\phi$, as the time derivatives are first order. Is this correct?

The coupled transport system and the two wave equations are analytically equivalent, as far as I understand. Can I recover the very initial conditions I have to choose for the coupled transport system, such that the problems are equivalent (based on the chosen initial conditions for the wave equation)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: for the system of first order PDEs
\begin{align}
\partial_t u + b\partial_x \phi &= 0, \tag{1a} \\
\partial_t \phi + b\partial_x u &= 0, \tag{1b}
\end{align}
you need one initial condition for $u$ and one for $\phi$, specifically
\begin{align}
u(x,0) &= u_0(x), \tag{2a} \\
\phi(x,0) &= \phi_0(x). \tag{2b}
\end{align}
On the other hand, for the second order PDE
$$
\partial_{tt} u - b^2 \partial_{xx} u = 0, \tag{3}
$$
you need two initial conditions, $u(x,0)$ and $\partial_t u(x,0)$. The first is provided by $(2\text{a})$, and the second can be derived from $(1\text{a})$ and $(2\text{b})$:
$$
\partial_t u(x,0)=-b\partial_x\phi(x,0)=-b\phi_0'(x). \tag{4}
$$

Comment: Thank you, very simple!